# Can I disable IPv6 when compiling avahi for arm device?

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, cross-compiling, avahi

So I want to build avahi for linux arm device, but currently my kernel doesn't support ipv6.

Is it possible if I want disable ipv6 feature on avahi? What `./configure` command argument do I need?

Also I will provide more information if you need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked inside the `configure` file in the avahi source-code, but I didn't find something that related to IPv6.

I solved my problem with building another toolchain that support IPv6. It was successfully build the avahi, but maybe I need disable IPv6 in avahi-daemon.conf instead because my kernel doesn't support IPv6.

Thank you.

**Update:**
I was successfully running avahi-daemon binary to publish a service. If I set `use-ipv6` in avahi-daemon.conf to `yes`, it will still running, but I am getting this message:

```
socket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol
Failed to create IPv6 socket, proceeding in IPv4 only mode
socket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol
```

So I will set `use-ipv6` to `no` instead, and of course the message disappear.